# What is the power consumption of HP Proliant SAS 15k hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant, sas

I have been looking at improving the power footprint of our server architecture and one way to achieve this might be to replace our current 15k SAS HDDs with SSD drives.

However, I have been unable to find the typical power consumption figures of these drives from the HP documentation.

What is an average power consumption of a 2.5" 15k SAS drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a 2,5" 15k SAS disk would use about 9 watt on average, compared to SSD which use almost nothing at idle and 2watt at load

http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/internal-hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/hdd/enterprise-performance-15k-hdd/#specs